# Save custom level logs into file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to save the infos of the logins that have succeded into a log file, I thought of creating a new level of logging and save into the log file only the logs with that specific level.
This is how I tried but I can't have it work properly:

log4j2-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{white} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="./logs/historicLog.log"
                     filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="login" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:3.0.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.1'
}

configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

AuthenticationService.java

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AuthenticationServiceApplication.class);
....
logger.log(Level.forName("login", 850), user.getUsername() + " logged in as admin");
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your root logger is still set on `INFO`, and your `com.authenticationservice` logger is on `TRACE`, both have level IDs lower then 850, so any log statements with a higher level will not be written.

However, i would suggest to not use a custom log level, but rather a specific logger name and configure that one then. E.g. like this:

In your AuthenticationService.java:

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("login");
```

In your log4j2-spring.xml:

```
<Logger name="login" level="info"> // Note, that you should have the same level configured than what you use in the code to log the messages
  <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Logger>
```

This would write all login related logs in the log file configured at `RollingFile`. With that solution you are a lot more flexible than with using a custom level, since you can redirect this to separate files, combine the statements with other loggers etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have edited the post with the updated .xml code, can you please check if I have done it correctly? Also in the .java file the logger.log(Level.forName("login", 850), user.getUsername() + " logged in as admin");
is still right?

Comment: Can you please reply @dunni?